# lodash groupBy on javascript or typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, group-by, lodash

i have following query result.

```
[
  {
    INTERVIEW_DT: "20220823",
    DEPT_ID: "c97852f5-3d71-41ae-81f7-bb5df2a321ba",
    RECRUIT_COUNT: 1,
    INTERVIEW_CNT: 1,
    PASS_CNT: 0,
  },
  {
    INTERVIEW_DT: "20220823",
    DEPT_ID: "d9608b11-fa24-4f53-bad4-0ea2cf375ade",
    RECRUIT_COUNT: 3,
    INTERVIEW_CNT: 1,
    PASS_CNT: 1,
  },
  {
    INTERVIEW_DT: "20220824",
    DEPT_ID: "c97852f5-3d71-41ae-81f7-bb5df2a321ba",
    RECRUIT_COUNT: 5,
    INTERVIEW_CNT: 3,
    PASS_CNT: 1,
  },
  {
    INTERVIEW_DT: "20220824",
    DEPT_ID: "d9608b11-fa24-4f53-bad4-0ea2cf375ade",
    RECRUIT_COUNT: 2,
    INTERVIEW_CNT: 2,
    PASS_CNT: 1,
  },
]
```

I need to groupBy "INTERVIEW_DT" and "DEPT_ID" with sum
top key is "DATE", "TOTAL".

"DATE" is group by INTERVIEW_DT and DEPT_ID
"TOTAL" group by DEPT_ID and then sum. regardless of "INTERVIEW_DT"

i want to following result using with javascript or typescript 
please help me.

```
{
    'DATE': [{
        '20220823': [{
            'c97852f5-3d71-41ae-81f7-bb5df2a321ba': {
                'RECRUIT_COUNT': 1,
                'INTERVIEW_CNT': 1,
                'PASS_CNT': 0
                },
            },
            {
                'd9608b11-fa24-4f53-bad4-0ea2cf375ade': {
                'RECRUIT_COUNT': 3,
                'INTERVIEW_CNT': 1,
                'PASS_CNT': 1
                }
            }
        ],
        '20220824': [{
            'c97852f5-3d71-41ae-81f7-bb5df2a321ba': {
                'RECRUIT_COUNT': 5,
                'INTERVIEW_CNT': 3,
                'PASS_CNT': 1
            },
        },
        {
            'd9608b11-fa24-4f53-bad4-0ea2cf375ade': {
                'RECRUIT_COUNT': 2,
                'INTERVIEW_CNT': 2,
                'PASS_CNT': 1
            }
        }
        ],
    }],
    'TOTAL': [{
        'c97852f5-3d71-41ae-81f7-bb5df2a321ba': {
            'RECRUIT_COUNT': 6,
            'INTERVIEW_CNT': 5,
            'PASS_CNT': 1
            },
        },
        {
            'd9608b11-fa24-4f53-bad4-0ea2cf375ade': {
            'RECRUIT_COUNT': 5,
            'INTERVIEW_CNT': 3,
            'PASS_CNT': 2
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'll use the famous group array of objects by key using `reduce` method. This time more than once. 2 loop of 2 nested loops.

After create an object that contains a tree we now need to convert it to the required "array" format. Both use `reduce` although slightly different.

```js
var input = [{
    INTERVIEW_DT: "20220823",
    DEPT_ID: "c97852f5-3d71-41ae-81f7-bb5df2a321ba",
    RECRUIT_COUNT: 1,
    INTERVIEW_CNT: 1,
    PASS_CNT: 0,
  },
  {
    INTERVIEW_DT: "20220823",
    DEPT_ID: "d9608b11-fa24-4f53-bad4-0ea2cf375ade",
    RECRUIT_COUNT: 3,
    INTERVIEW_CNT: 1,
    PASS_CNT: 1,
  },
  {
    INTERVIEW_DT: "20220824",
    DEPT_ID: "c97852f5-3d71-41ae-81f7-bb5df2a321ba",
    RECRUIT_COUNT: 5,
    INTERVIEW_CNT: 3,
    PASS_CNT: 1,
  },
  {
    INTERVIEW_DT: "20220824",
    DEPT_ID: "d9608b11-fa24-4f53-bad4-0ea2cf375ade",
    RECRUIT_COUNT: 2,
    INTERVIEW_CNT: 2,
    PASS_CNT: 1,
  },
]

// this obj is the nested tree of everything
var obj = input.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg[item.INTERVIEW_DT]  ??= {}
  agg[item.INTERVIEW_DT][item.DEPT_ID] ??= {
    RECRUIT_COUNT: 0,
    INTERVIEW_CNT: 0,
    PASS_CNT: 0
  };
  agg[item.INTERVIEW_DT][item.DEPT_ID].RECRUIT_COUNT += item.RECRUIT_COUNT
  agg[item.INTERVIEW_DT][item.DEPT_ID].INTERVIEW_CNT += item.INTERVIEW_CNT
  agg[item.INTERVIEW_DT][item.DEPT_ID].PASS_CNT += item.PASS_CNT
  return agg
}, {})


function obj_2_arr(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce(function(agg, [key, value]) {
    var elem = {}
    elem[key] = value;
    agg.push(elem)
    return agg;
  }, []);
}

// convert to arr(s)
var DATE = Object.entries(obj).reduce(function(agg, [key, value]) {
  var DEPT = obj_2_arr(value);
  var elem = {}
  elem[key] = DEPT;
  agg.push(elem)
  return agg;
}, []);


// now TOTAL, same idea
var obj = input.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg[item.DEPT_ID] = agg[item.DEPT_ID] || {
    RECRUIT_COUNT: 0,
    INTERVIEW_CNT: 0,
    PASS_CNT: 0
  }
  agg[item.DEPT_ID].RECRUIT_COUNT += item.RECRUIT_COUNT
  agg[item.DEPT_ID].INTERVIEW_CNT += item.INTERVIEW_CNT
  agg[item.DEPT_ID].PASS_CNT += item.PASS_CNT
  return agg
}, {})

// convert to arr
var TOTAL = obj_2_arr(obj);

var result = {
  DATE,
  TOTAL
}
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```